# Alphabetizing a list of facts using repeat in prolog

Tags: list, sorting, prolog, set, repeat

I have a list of facts like this:

```
set(z,a).
set(z,3).
set(z,k).
set(z,10).
set(z,z).
set(z,1).
```

And I need to sort them like this:

```
?- sorted(z, List).
List = [1, 3, 10, a, k, z].
```

How this doesn't seem too bad. But the problem is that I'm required to use **repeat** to do it.

I have no idea how to do it using repeat. Here's two simple ways I found out without repeat:

```
sorted(Set, Z) :-
    setof(X, set(Set,X), Z).


sorted2(Set,Sorted) :-
    findall(X, set(Set,X), List),
    sort(List, Sorted).
```

Here's something I tried doing on my own:

```
member(X, [Y|T]) :- X = Y; member(X, T).

smallest(Set,A) :-
    findall(X, set(Set,X), Xs),
    sort(Xs, [A|_]).


sorted(Set, List) :-
    List is [],
    repeat,
    smallest(Set, CurrentSmallest),
    not(member(CurrentSmallest, List)) ->  
        append(List, CurrentSmallest, List), % don't know how to keep adding to this list
    length(List,ListLength),
    aggregate_all(count, set(Set,_), FactCount),
    ListLength = FactCount.
```

Idea here being that I start with any empty list. Then we start repeating and taking smaller elements one by one. If we haven't already added the element into the answer we add it to the list. Otherwise we don't. Once the list is the same length as our fact base we succeed and stop the repeat.

But adding to the same list clearly doesn't work like that. Also right now it doesn't work when we have duplicate elements in the set. This is very confusing.

**EDIT:**

I tried changing it a bit and using asserts for the List like Daniel Lyons said. At the moment it still doesn't work. One reason for that that I suspect of is that it keeps taking the same CurrentSmallest on every repeat. I need it to stop doing that, but I have no idea how.

```
:- dynamic list/1.

assert(list([])).

member(X, [Y|T]) :- X = Y; member(X, T).

smallest(Set,A) :-
    findall(X, set(Set,X), Xs),
    sort(Xs, [A|_]).

sorted(Set, Answer) :-
    repeat,
    smallest(Set, CurrentSmallest),
    list(List),
    not(member(CurrentSmallest, List)) -> 
        (    
        append(List, CurrentSmallest, List2),
        retract(list(List)),
        assert(list(List2))
        ),
    list(Answer),
    length(Answer,ListLength),
    aggregate_all(count, set(Set,_), FactCount),
    ListLength = FactCount.
```

Comment: You're going to have to use `asserta/1` or `assertz/1` to keep state mutably, because you're right, you can't mutate a list in Prolog.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I tried implementing it. Unfortunately I clearly still have some problems, at the moment it doesn't work. I put the newer version in the original post.

Comment: @DanielLyons sorry about being pedantic, but you _can_ mutate a list in Prolog, even though details might be implementation dependent.

Comment: Using `findall` and `sort` inside the `repeat` loop completely defeats the purpose in my opinion. Or even more so, predicates from `library(aggregate)`.

Comment: @Boris how? I'm not aware of any standard way to do it. Anyway, it certainly doesn't work the way a new user would expect.

Comment: @DanielLyons No, it is probably implementation dependent, but in SWI-Prolog at least it would be the ["Non-logical operations on terms"](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=setarg) that describes it. Either way, creating a sorted list using `repeat` seems like an asinine task for a beginner.

Comment: @Boris on that we completely agree... doing this the easy way is trivial, doing it the hard way is a totally unnecessary, unhelpful exercise in frustration with no pedagogical reward.

Comment: @DanielLyons There must be something behind these questions that we aren't told. You should check the previous questions by OP.

Comment: @DanielLyons What makes the least sense to me so far is that using `repeat` in particular is stated as a requirement, but infact, the table of facts makes `repeat` completely unnecessary even for a non-logical solution.

Comment: @PadaKatel where is the requirement to use `repeat` coming from? It seems to make the assignment almost impossible, in addition to being both extremely bad Prolog style and very hard to accomplish.

Comment: It's schoolwork I'm afraid. I am well aware how bad it is, but there's nothing I can do about it. 

Honestly, at this point I don't really care how terrible and also pointless the final would be. I have the query and the output and the requirement of 'repeat'. As long as those boxes are ticked I would be fine with any solution.

Comment: @PadaKatel why don't you solve it the right way and then use a failure-driven loop over the solution to print it out... maybe your clueless prof will accept that. :)

Comment: @DanielLyons Unfortunately the input and output need to exactly as given. Another prolog program runs ours.